# How to get "Super" key working on Drevo Blademaster Pro?

Tags: keyboard

I have the wireless Blademaster Pro mechanical keyboard, currently I have it connected via USB.

Ctrl and Alt keys are working fine but the Super key (labeled WIN and Option) does nothing when pressed. It should make all windows viable and allow tabbing between them. I can confirm this using another keyboard.

Using `xev` pressing Super on my old keyboard I see:

```
PropertyNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x3c00001,
    atom 0x18b (_GTK_EDGE_CONSTRAINTS), time 22310600, state PropertyNewValue
```

But on my new keyboard, nothing is output. Also while all other keys are backlit with red, the WIN key is backlit blue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Press FN then the WIN key and it becomes backlit Red like the other keys and works as expected. I don't know why this works.

Comment: This is because (most if not all) Drevo keyboards support both Mac and Windows. Under the Windows config, the super key works as expected with Linux, but when you switch to the Mac config the super key becomes "option" for use with "command option" key combos in Mac OS (it actually should say option underneath "Win"). You switch between these configs with Fn + Win.

Answer (score 1):

FN+Win works because that is a mode on the keyboard to disable the Super key for gaming.
There is also a DIP switch on the back to change to a "mac" mode turning it into an "Option" key. Yey for stupidly proliferated and confusing 'standards'.